# Angular-ui select2 not working when mixing angular with twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

I'm using angular-ui and bootstrap in the same web application and I've an issue when trying to use the ui-select2 component: everything works fine except that upon selecting an element in the drop-down list it's not shown in the component, it shows empty, though the ng-model associated variable is correctly updated.
This strange behavior goes away if I remove the inclusion of the bootstrap.js file from the main page.
Is there anyone who has experienced using both angular-js and bootstrap at the same time and/or who knows about any tweaks to apply for having them work together?

**UPDATE:**

The ui-select2 component is inside an input-append div, just removing the div solves the problem. I've created a fork of the Angular-ui ui-select2 original sandbox demo [here](http://plnkr.co/OMEzYWlosam0c84L926U?p=preview). You can go to the "Version 2" example and check that selecting a value in the list correctly update the model but doesn't updates the input element.

Comment: I've just discovered that the issue is caused by the select2 component being inside an input-append div, just removing the div solves the problem. Anyway the question is still valid, I've just narrowed the way, seems that it's some css clash.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something to demonstrate the code and behavior?

Comment: @ProLoser Thanks for your interest, I've updated my question with a link to an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bottom line is that you cannot use `input-append` alongside Select2 natively. The input that you put into the HTML is actually going to be hidden, and Select2 injects additional DOM elements (divs, lists and inputs) that all will be hidden/shown and all have their own respective CSS.

The problem you are having is due to conflicting CSS between Bootstrap and Select2.

You should consider A: Not using input-append, B: Rewriting or tweaking the CSS to un-hide the relevant elements, C: Use typeahead or some other solution that plays nicely with Bootstrap's CSS instead.

You can checkout the [AngularUI Bootstrap Project](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) or check out [this Plunker / Gist](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:4464334?p=preview) that shows you how to run Bootstrap directives using the AngularUI Passthrough directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll go with the solution shown in your Plunker. By the way, I've seen your are the author of "AngularJS Tips and Tricks", great job!